# MySQL query with subtraction on other rows

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(t.transactionAmt) as transactionAmt, c.categoryType, MONTH(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) as transactionMonth,  YEAR(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) as transactionYear
FROM transaction_db t INNER JOIN category_db c
ON t.categoryID = c.categoryID
WHERE t.accountID = '12'
GROUP BY c.categoryType, MONTH(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y'))
ORDER BY MONTH(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) DESC
```

This is the output:

Is there any way to query it in such a way such that if there are from same transactionMonth, I take the row with categoryType 0 minus away the row with categoryType 1?

For instance, for month 5, I take the 2233 subtract with 464 to get the result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view from your query (see [Create VIEW Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) for details), that will be used in subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  cat1.transactionAmt - cat2.transactionAmt AS transactionDiff
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE categoryType = 0) AS cat1 
  JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM  MyView AS cat1 WHERE categoryType = 1) AS cat2
  USING(transactionMonth);
```

Or try to use [Control Flow Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). For example:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(IF(c.categoryType=0, t.transactionAmt, -t.transactionAmt)) as transactionAmt, 
  MONTH(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) as transactionMonth,  
  YEAR(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) as transactionYear
FROM 
  transaction_db t INNER JOIN category_db c
  ON t.categoryID = c.categoryID
WHERE t.accountID = '12'
GROUP BY MONTH(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y'))
ORDER BY MONTH(str_to_date(t.transactionDate, '%d/%m/%Y')) DESC
```

Comment: Is there any way to insert sql query directly rather than create a view in this case?

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm! Let me try to understand the solution now!

Comment: @EmmaHannah, the query will be working correctly with only two possible values for the `categoryType` field: 0 or 1. If the set of values ​​accepted by `categoryType` does not correspond to this condition, all values of `transactionAmt` that `categoryType` not equals to 0 will be subtracted from `transactionAmt` that `categoryType` equals to 0.

Comment: Sorry but does that means let's say for this month I only have categoryType 1 but without any categoryType 1, this will return 0 as the amount after subtraction?

Comment: @EmmaHannah, see `IF` statement in the query. If `c.categoryType` is equal to 0, then a `transactionAmt` value will be added, in all other cases a `transactionAmt` value will be substracted.

Comment: I see thanks so much! The solution and explanation are so clear!

Comment: But is there any way to format it such that let's say if the month is single digit, format it to become 04, 05 etc?

Comment: @EmmaHannah, use [LPAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function. In your case the `len` attribute is 2 and `padstr` is 0.